# How does column transformation work in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

I have created an estimator to clean a column and then used this estimator for column transformation. Here is my estimator

```
class CabinImputer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, imp='Z'):
        self.imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.NaN, strategy='constant', fill_value=imp)
        pat = re.compile(r'^[A-Z]')
        self.categorizer = np.vectorize(lambda x: pat.match(x).group())
    def fit(self, X=None, y=None):
        return self 
    def transform(self, X):
        X = self.imputer.fit_transform(X)
        print(X[1:8, 0])
        X[:, 0] = self.categorizer(X[:, 0])
        print(X.shape)
        return X

imputer = ColumnTransformer([
    ('cabin_imp', CabinImputer(), ['Cabin']),
    ('Emb_imp', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent'), ['Embarked'])
])
```

The estimator simply imputes all missing values with 'Z' and extracts the first capital letter from each element of the column.

But whenever I try to transform my data using the column transformer. The following error shows up.
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

When I simply use the transformer by

```
cbimp = CabinImputer()
cbimp.fit_transform(data.Cabin.to_frame())
```

no error shows and the first print function gives the expected output `['C85' 'Z' 'C123' 'Z' 'Z' 'E46' 'Z']`, but when the column transformer is used `imputer.fit_transform(data)`, the above error shows up, and first print function gives output like `['C85' 'missing_value' 'C123' 'missing_value' 'missing_value' 'E46' 'missing_value']`

What is going wrong here?

**Edit1:**

With further research I found that the main problem is whenever I use the `ColumnTransformer`, the `fill_value` parameter does not get passed! Why??!

**Edit2:**
Eventually solved the problem by creating the `SimpleImputer` object in `fit` function. But I don't what was the problem with earlier code

```
def fit(self, X=None, y=None):
    # self.imp = imp in __init__ function
    self.imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.NaN, strategy='constant', fill_value=self.imp)
    return self
```